# change projection on geom_sf map

Tags: r, mapping, spatial, shapefile, rgeo

I need to map the east coast of US and Canada with `ggplot` and `geom_sf`, but I want to do so with a projection that will make Florida to Nova Scotia less exaggerated from East to West, such as Lambert Conformal, show in Fig 3.3 here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oce/vignettes/map_projections.html

How do I do this in ggplot with geom_sf?

Here's the section I have so far:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf")

world %>%
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(fill = "darkseagreen3") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-87, -50), ylim = c(18, 50), expand = FALSE)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(color="transparent", fill = "transparent"),
        plot.background = element_rect(color="transparent", fill = "transparent"))
```

This is pretty much the area I need, but I want it to be not so wide east-to-west. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a simple features object, you can easily change the coordinate system as follows:

```
reprojected_World <- st_transform(world, 'EPSG:3082')
```

Here, the coordinate system chosen is the Lambert Conformal. For codes of other projections, see https://epsg.org/home.html. Good luck on your project.

Comment: I tried something similar, but when I run
```
reprojected_World %>%
ggplot()+
geom_sf()
```
I get a crazy result. The map is the right shape, but I don't know how to crop it with this coordinate system.

Comment: @Jake L That is true. Upon first look, the results are very peculiar, but that is just because of the way the projection works. It is not a projection meant to be used for the whole earth, so you need to adjust your frame with coord_sf(). Plotting without adjusting the frame give something that is barely recognizable as a map.

Comment: If you check the bounding box once it is in the correct form. This will give you an idea of how you need to set the x and y limits, but it'll take some trial and error. This should give you start that centers on the US: coord_sf(xlim = c(-4378820, 8378820), ylim = c(0, 12922790) )